# Post checked checkboxes to controller action without using HTML helper like Html.CheckboxList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have a list of items and I would like to delete items that are checked in a list of checkboxes.

I can't use something like `CheckboxList` since I'm using `Grid.Mvc` to display my lines. That is why I create checkboxes in each line with `column.add("<input type="checkbox".....>);`.

Every checkbox has its own ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="4">...
```

I would like to know how to pass all checked checkbox IDs to the controller (from there I will perform delete operations). How can I post an array of checked IDs from my form to my controller action with one button press?

Comment: You're going to need to write some JavaScript or jQuery to parse them all to send them. Other than that advice, we'll need to see what you've tried that still doesn't work.

Comment: this link would be helpful. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: I Can't use checkboxlist since I'm using Grid.Mvc to display my lines. Thats why I create checkboxes in each line with column.add("<input type="checkbox".....>);

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Example of generated HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="deletedItems" value="3"> Some label for 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="deletedItems" value="4"> Some label for 4</label>
...
<button type="submit">Submit</submit>
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(int[] deletedItems)
{
    // deletedItems contains all values that were checked
    // when the submit button was clicked. Here you can
    // loop through the array of IDs and delete by ID.
    ...
}
```

Note that the checkboxes do not have an `id` attribute. It is not used for model binding. Instead it has a `name` attribute named "deletedItems" that matches the name of the argument of the `MyAction` controller action, and that is what is used when model binding. The `value` attribute of checked checkboxes will be used to populate the `deletedItems` array of `int[]`.

Comment: Simplest solution rather than passing in the entire form.

Comment: This is a bad solution. Most people will need more than just the checkbox result.. It should come via the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you want generated html like

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="deletedItems" value="3"> Some label for 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="deletedItems" value="4"> Some label for 4</label>
```

Then you can use the following code

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("selectedItems", new { @value = @item.checkId })</td> 
<td><input id="selectedItems" name="selectedItems" type="checkbox" value="11503" />
    <input name="selectedItems" type="hidden" value="false" /> 
</td>
```

It won't pass selectedItems to controller.